# How to use Floating Button Over Vertical Scroll View?

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

The Gmail Android App Floating Button

I want to add a floating button over a scroll view in Android. Such that, even if I scroll the layout, the button should remain constant at the given position (bottom-right) in this case. Just like the Gmail android mobile app, they have a send mail button intact at the bottom-right and the background is scrollable.

[image]

Comment: Paste code what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add floating action button on top of scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651418/how-to-add-floating-action-button-on-top-of-scrollview)

Comment: Just don't put the floating button inside the scroll view in your layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the button on top of the layout instead of in the recyclerview it wont move when you scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">



<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `ScrollView`, it's a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). You can use `CoordinatorLayout` for this purpose

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <Your layout with Recycler View/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you still want to use a ScrollView, just put it as a sibling of your RecyclerView with gravity bottom.

Answer (score 0):

make the Scroll View inside constraint layout don't make the main parent layout the scroll view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```