# Android - Floating Action Bar is behind the BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following situation: I have an app with one `activity` and many `fragments`. The `fragments` are swapped in and out using the `NavHostFragment` in the activity layout.
The common views that all `fragments` are sharing (e.g. `CoordinatorLayout` , `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbar`, `Toolbar` etc.) are also located in the `activity` layout. Some of the `fragment` layouts has views like `RecyclerView` and `FloatingActionBar`.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

In the .gif file, you can see that FloatingActionButton is behind the BottomNavigationBar. Only when the user scrolls down, the FloatingActionButton is shown completely to the user. What I want is that they should be able to see the button completely even when they are not scrolling down.
(Note that the RecyclerView has no items because I wanted to keep the focus on the button. The behavior of the button is the same with items.)

This is how my `activity_main.xml` looks like :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav_view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidApp.AppBarOverlay">

                    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                        app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline5" />
                        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

                    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    app:defaultNavHost="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/coordinator_layout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_actions" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
    
</layout>
```

And this is the layout of one of my Fragments:

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.androidapp.ItemsFragmentViewModel"/>

    </data>
    

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/progress_bar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.create()}"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/list_items"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

Maybe I messed the activity layout a little bit, I do not know. Everything works, only the FloatingActionButton destroys it.
Can someone help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951487/how-to-use-floating-button-over-vertical-scroll-view

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is that they should be able to see the button completely
> even when they are not scrolling down.

The best approach would be placing the `FloatingActionButton` inside the `CoordinatorLayout` of the `activity_main` layout to achieve the desire effects such as scrolling, hiding or whatever you like.

As already mentioned here: [Fragment layout with FAB conflict with CoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330651/fragment-layout-with-fab-conflict-with-coordinatorlayout)

---

**The second part:**

All you need to do is to remove the `ConstraintLayout` in the `activity_main` layout so that the DrawerLayout will be able to recognize the `CoordinatorLayout` as its child. After that, use the `BottomNavigationView` inside the `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                    app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline5" />
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: are you sure ? the BottomNavigationView is on top when I am doing this.

Comment: Sure, I forgot to add:  `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to the `BottomNavigationView`. I'll update the answer.